# ActiveAdmin filter users by role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I'd like to be able to filter devise users in active admin so that I can show a list of users, then filter those users by what role they have.

What I have is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_permissions
  has_many :roles, :through => :user_permissions

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_permissions
  has_many :users, :through => :user_permissions

class UserPermission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :role
```

Then the filter is:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  filter :roles, as: :select, collection: proc { Role.all }
```

But what I get is this error:

```
    undefined method `role_ids_eq' for #<MetaSearch::Searches::User:0x0000012a2f7170>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about active admin working of filters but if you are talking about queries filter then this will work-

```
User.where(:role => 'admin')
```

**Note:** The above query will give all the users with the role `admin`.

As mentioned, Rails 3 introduces a new query interface for performing finds in Active Record.

> http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  filter :user_roles, as: :select, collection: proc { Role.all }
```

if the relationship is okay that should work